# Error trying to execute a customized command for running migrations

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am trying to create a command to perform all the migrations I have at once but in a way that assigns each of them to a different batch.

As a first attempt, the command I have created contains:

```
class CreateDBStructure extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'database:create';

    ...

    public function handle(){
        $this->call('migrate', [
            '--path' => 'database/migrations/2021_01_01_create_roles_table.php',
            'name' => 'CreateRolesTable'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In kernel:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\CreateDBStructure',
];
```

And the migration class name:

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration {

    ...

}
```

I am getting the following error:

> php artisan database:create
>
> The "name" argument does not exist.

I don't quite understand why I'm getting this error. Please, could you help me?

*php artisan cache:clear*, *composer dump-autoload* and other similar commands didn't work.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are calling `make:migration` that creates a migration in the given directory path, which exists as a file. Hence the error `mkdir(): File exists`.

Comment: Why do yon need a custom command for that? Just run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: The problem is that if I just run *php artisan migrate*, it creates all the migrations with the same batch and I don't want to do it in that way. I would like to have each migration with a different batch.

Comment: Sorry for the "make:migration" command. I was a mistake because I tried many times and in many different ways. The command "migrate" returns "The "name" argument does not exist." but I passed a "name" argument. I update the question

Comment: migrate command has an option for this:
--step                       Force the migrations to be run so they can be rolled back individually
. So run `php artisan migrate --step`